# Cannot create private message queue on remote server

Tags: msmq, messaging

I am unable to create a queue on a remote server and the error i get is :

```
Cannot create a queue with the path FormatName:DIRECT=OS:server\private$\q
```

the code is as below:

```
Dim q As MessageQueue
q = MessageQueue.Create("FormatName:Direct=OS:Server\private$\queue")
```

I have tried with OS, TCP, HTTP and all the possible options given [here](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2007/02/msmq_sending_message_to_remote.html) but I have not been able to create a queue on remote machine. I am running Win 7 Enterprise on my dev box and Win Server 2003 R2 on the MSMQ server.

Am i missing some security / permission settings on the server or some other configuration ? would appreciate any help possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create remote private queues.

You will need to manually create them at the remote machine or run a process there that does what you need.

Comment: in that case, i should still be able to create public queues and unfortunately I am unable to create remote public queues also.

Comment: That is a different problem :-)  You need to have MSMQ installed in Active Directory Integrated mode and not workgroup mode for public queues to be created. If you think MSMQ is installed correctly but you atill have problems then please supply sample line of code and the error returned.

Comment: How do i ensure that its installed in AD Integrated mode and how can i verify the mode in which MSMQ is installed ?

Comment: In Control Panel, add/remove programs, etc. where you install MSMQ, AD Integration should be a sub-component. If you can open up message queuing in Computer Management and the is a public folder without a red cross through it then you are in AD integrated mode. You should be able to create a public queue there. If you can in Computer Management but not in your code then your code is not using the right approach - you can't use formatname, for example. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/02/26/difference-between-path-name-and-format-name-when-accessing-msmq-queues.aspx

Comment: I got the AD setup / MSMQ Integrated mode done based on the article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749102(WS.10).aspx and restarted the service. I do see the Public Queues now in the MSMQ server but i am still unable to create a queue remotely under Public Queues.

Comment: Dim q As New MessageQueue
        MessageQueue.Create("FormatName:DIRECT=OS:developer\q1", False)

Comment: If i create the remote queue manually, should i be able to send messages to the remote public queue ? I created a public queue manually and then tried to post message. the message sending code did not throw any error but the message did not show up in the public queue.

Comment: If you look in my blog link above, you will see a bright yellow highlight that emphasises you need to use path name to create public queues. This is because you need to contact Active Directory to create the queue - direct formatname doesn't talk to AD.

Comment: The message sending code did not throw any errors because you didn't ask it to. The Send operation only covers putting the message in the outgoing queue - you only get an error if that local operation fails. To understand why delivery to the remote queue failed, use negative source journaling.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, John. the dev box is not in AD so its not able to communicate with the server. I think once i manage to move the dev box to AD, it should work fine. Once again, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create remote queues. Look at [MessageQueue.Create Method documenatation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yka0xsf%28VS.80%29.aspx).