# Create private message queue on remote machine

Tags: windows, powershell, message-queue, powershell-remoting

I've read that in C# we cannot create a private queue on a remote machine:
[Cannot create private message queue on remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063672/cannot-create-private-message-queue-on-remote-server)

My question is: in PowerShell script, can we do that? Here is my sample script:

```
echo "Loading System.Messaging..."
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.Messaging" )
$msmq = [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]

echo "Create the queue"

$qName = "remoteserver\private$\testqueue"  
if($msmq::Exists($qName))
{
    echo ($qName + " already exists ")           
}
else
{
    echo ($qName + " doesn't exists and now to create ......")      

    $q = $msmq::Create( $qName, $TRUE )     

    echo "Private queues has been created"
}
```

And it says "Invalid queue path name". I also tried some format like: `FormatName:DIRECT=OS:remoteserver\private$\testqueue`

And result is the same. Any possibilities?

Comment: What you really need is `Enter-PSSession`, I think. Then create a queue you need "locally".

Comment: Hi abatishchev, I tried your solution. The strange thing is: there is error when executing the script, but I cannot see the queue on remote server.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it appears remote queue creation via the System.Messaging API is not supported, but all is not lost! Use powershell remoting (as @abatishchev has suggested) to create a local queue and it works just fine.

I saved your script to a file (create-queue.ps1) modified slightly to set `$queueName = '.\private$\testqueue'`. Then I used `invoke-command` to run the script on the remote server:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName remoteserver -FilePath .\create-queue.ps1
```

This assumes you've gotten powershell remoting enabled on the target server. You should receive the output from the server when it completes so you should be able to diagnose any errors.

You could of course wrap this all in a nice powershell function if you have to do it a lot:

```
function Create-MessageQueue {
    param([string]$QueueName,[string]$ComputerName = ".")

    $script = {
        param($qName)

        [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Messaging') | out-debug
        $msmq = [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]
        $queuePath = ".\private`$\$qName"  
        if($msmq::Exists($queuePath))
        {
            echo "$queuePath already exists "
        }
        else
        {
            echo "'$queuePath' doesn't exists and now to create ......"
            $msmq::Create($queuePath,$true)     
            echo "Private queue '$queuePath' has been created"
        }
    }

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock $script -ArgumentList $QueueName
}
```

Comment: Hi mike Z, that's awesome!

Comment: Does this actually work? I am still receiving an "invalid queue path name" error when attempting to create a remote private queue on a machine with Windows Remote Management running and enabled per https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx

Comment: @ChadLazette AFAIK it works. I tested it when I wrote the post.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few things that I gleaned from the documentation:

1. This has nothing to do with PowerShell. You can just as well write it in C# and it wouldn't work.
2. The documentation for [Exists()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states that »The Exists(String) method does not support the `FormatName` prefix.« so your alternative way of stating the queue name cannot work either.
3. `$` in double-quoted strings has significance in PowerShell. It's for inline variable expansion. It is of no significance here because it doesn't form a valid variable name (or subexpression) and thus remains verbatim. But you *should* use single-quoted strings here. If in doubt, just dump the string on the pipeline to see its value.
4. The documentation for [Create()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8f3sy4ta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has the following fun table:

   > The following table shows whether this method is available in various Workgroup modes.
   >
   > ```
   > Workgroup mode                                              Available
   > =====================================================================
   > Local computer                                              Yes
   > Local computer and direct format name                       Yes
   > Remote computer                                             No
   > Remote computer and direct format name                      No
   > ```

   which simply could mean that it doesn't work with remote computer names.

Comment: Hi Joey, so does that mean there is NO-WAY to create a private message queue on remote server via Powershell?

Comment: I have no idea and never worked with any of this. I just pointed out a few things from the documentation which might help. Again, this has nothing to do with PowerShell. You could write the exact same code in C# and it would not work. You're only calling methods of framework objects after all.